# How to add disable command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want that when user uses the command disable {command_name} . the command gets diable i dont know how to do this please help me out.
please share with a example

```
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
       await ctx.send("hi")
```

if i want the the hello command to be disabled then ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable a command by using [`command.update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=update#discord.ext.commands.Command.update). You can disable it by doing `command.update(enable=False)`. Further explanations will be in the code provided below.

Please note: Next time you ask a question like this, **provide what you have tried beforehand**, most people will not entertain you with providing the full code.

```py
@bot.command()
async def disable(ctx, command_name=None):
    if command_name == None: 
        # comes here if no command is given
        await ctx.send("Please give me a command you want to disable!")
        return

    try:
        # the bot will try to get the command
        command = bot.get_command(command_name)
        # then the bot will try to disable it
        command.update(enabled=False)
        # command.update(enabled=True) allows you to enable the command
    except:
        # this gets sent if the bot can't: a) get the command or b) disable the command
        await ctx.send("That isn't a valid command!")
        return

    # finally, if the command gets successfully disabled, it sends this message
    await ctx.send(f"I have disabled the command {command_name}")
```

[image: Command working as seen here]

(PS: The last error message was something programmed into my bot beforehand, you may want to have an error-handler)

Comment: If this helped you answer your question, do click on the tick beneath the up/down votes of this answer to accept it @akul07 